# Change browser cursor with Prototype.js

Tags: javascript, css, browser, prototypejs, mouse-cursor

I'm having problem changing the cursor when the page is loaded; my code is:

```js
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
     $$('select').each(function(s) {
        var ajaxRequest = new Ajax.Request(
            '/some_ajax_proc',
            {
```

When the page loads, the cursor doesn't change. However it does with no problem in other event listeners further on such as:

```js
   $('mytxt').observe('change', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
   }
```

UPDATE: OK, it DOES change the cursor, but since there's a `document.body.style.cursor = 'default';` after the Ajax loop, it changes it back immediatly so I guess it is a threads issue. Any hints in this case ?

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this in? Works for me in newest Safari on Mac.

Comment: Can you the show the issue using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
   onCreate: function() {
                if (Ajax.activeRequestCount === 1) {
                   //Code for change the cursor, something like this:
                   document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
                }
             },
   onComplete: function() {
                  if (Ajax.activeRequestCount === 0) {
                     // End loading...
                     ....
                  }
               }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this syntax:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  $(document.body).setStyle({
    cursor: 'wait'
  });
});
```

This works for me, but the thing of it is, do you have elements with either cursors defined, or which have other cursor styles (perhaps draggable items or clickable links) which override?

I'd look to see whether the `<body>` tag is actually having the style actually applied using something like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but no luck. I don't think it's a style issue ... it works just fine afterwards as I mentioned. I recently added more info just in case.

Comment: @xain how can I replicate your setup? This code works for me. Possibly  you have this code interacting with something else? More information about what you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: I think adding an Ajax.Request inside the 'load' event following the setting the cursor in 'wait' would do. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Since, you are already using jquery.

```
$('mytxt').observe('change', function() {
   $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
}
```

Comment: Anything wrong, with this answer. Please provide some comment downvoter.